# Call for [virtual-reality] on UX.SE

Tags: discussion

I will be opening a couple of virtual reality related questions of which I will be answering a lot this weekend myself probably, but I do first want to give space to the community to answer them and ask more similar questions.

Virtual Reality is a **HUGE** new field especially in regards to UX and UI design, however it is currently not present on UX.SE whatsoever (like literally 0). Right now there is no good and organized source for information on this topic either, it being spread out over various chaotic forums, old research and a lot of the work being done by programmers rather than UX minded people. It would be interesting to see whether we could make UX.SE (via Google) a go-to place for questions like this (it slowly is crawling up my google results for general web related UX questions), similar in how SO (via Google) is the go-to place for programming related questions. Right now their is a chance to build UX.SE up as a real brand as this is a growing and vibrant space. So, the concrete reason I am posting here is to ask and motivate active users here to ask these questions, but also to spend time researching these things. VR is only going to become bigger so it is time well invested.

Btw, I will be prepending at least my own VR questions with the following note:

> **NOTE:** Virtual Reality is a developing field. The [Facebook Oculus Rift][1] and [Sony Morpheus][2] just being some of the players. A lot of time is put into UX design as that's the hardest part to nail, so when answering VR related questions please indicate your experience, but do feel free to attempt answering even with limited experience. Answers containing research from the previous VR boom are also much appreciated.
>
> [1]: http://oculusvr.com 
>    [2]: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Morpheus_%28virtual_reality%29

Feel free to use if you believe it's appropriate.

Comment: Provided they're focussed on the UX angle of the VR / Rift / Morpheus and not developement questions then they're more than welcome on the site, yes. I'd say your prepended content is more suited to the tag-wiki of the [tag:virtual-reality] tag than being added into every question though. But probably add in a bit more description about what the tag actually means, as well as the links and reasoning for it existing that you have here.

Comment: @JonW: Obviously@your first point, and regarding your second, this would be indeed possible if such a mindset would become an official policy. (Currently writing a simple descriptive tag wiki)

Comment: @JonW: Ah, just saw your edit, yes, I am writing a more traditional tag wiki right now yeah.

Comment: Seems on topic, given the caveat mentioned by @JonW. As long as it's about design and UX rather than implementation and programming VR is as on topic as 2D interaction and display.